# Механизм запрета выполнения внешних команд, если программа запущена с ключом?

Tags: perl

Перловики!

Как в перле запретить выполнять внешние команды, если программа запущена с каким-либо ключом, предназначенным именно для таких целей?

Примитивный пример:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
...
...
...
...
system('ping -c5 www.host.tld');
...
...
```

Необходимо; если скрипт запущен без какого-либо ключа, выполнить внешнюю команду: `system('ping -c5 www.host.tld');`

Если же, пользователь запустил команду с ключом, то не выполнять внешнюю команду: `system('ping -c5 www.host.tld');`

Comment: Эм-м, проверять @ARGV на наличие переданных ключей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ((defined $ARGV[0]) && ($ARGV[0] eq '-noping')) {
...
} else {
...
}
```

А для нормального разбора опций есть Getopt::Std и Getopt::Long.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works!